# Using ArrayList get(i) to give parameters to create object doesn't work

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this problem. I'm creating a polynomial program, where I can subtract, add and multiply.

However I come across this error, I can't really pinpoint, why this happens.

First I have my Polynomial.java , I create an arraylist of two inputs, then I sort them based on the exponent, then I loop through this list, if the exponent matches, than a new pair will be created based on adding the coefficients and using the original exponent.

```
public Polynoom subtract(Polynoom that) {
    Polynoom subtract = new Polynoom(); 
    subtract.termen.addAll(that.termen);
    for (int i = 0; i < subtract.termen.size(); i++) {
        subtract.termen.get(i).coef = subtract.termen.get(i).coef * -1; 
    }
    subtract.termen.addAll(this.termen);
    Collections.sort(subtract.termen);
    subtract.removeDoubles(); 
    return subtract; 
}
```

This will create a list of pairs, with a double and an integer. For example:

```
-1.0 2
-1.0 1
 1.0 1
 2.0 0
```

Then I have a method that will look for pair with the same exponent, if so, then it will add the coefficient and takes the exponent of the first pair.

```
    private void removeDoubles() {

    for (int i = 0; i < this.termen.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (this.termen.get(i).exponent == this.termen.get(i + 1).exponent) {
            this.termen.set(i, new Pair((this.termen.get(i).coef + this.termen.get(i + 1).coef), (this.termen.get(i).exponent)));
            this.termen.remove(i + 1); 
            i --; 
        }       
    }
}
```

However, somehow the second argument I pass in the new Pair doesn't work.

If i for example change the new Pair to:

```
this.termen.set(i, new Pair(13, 2));
result difference: 1.0x^2 + 13.0x^2 + 2.0 (this is correct)
```

If i for example change new Pair to:

```
this.termen.set(i, new Pair(13, this.termen.get(i).exponent);
result difference: -1.0x^2 + x^1 + 2.0 (this is not correct)
```

Why if i set the new pair manually, it will work? Why doesn't it work why I use the this.termen.get.exponent? Because I basically do the same: putting an integer when creating a new Pair object.

Can anyone give me a tip? :)

Thanks!

EDIT:

My termen class, is part of my Polynomial class, and termen is an custom arraylist of the type pair.

```
class Polynoom implements PolynoomInterface {


ArrayList<Paar> termen = new ArrayList<Paar>();
```

And my pair class:

```
class Paar implements Comparable <Paar> {

double coef;
int exponent;

Paar(double a, int b) {
    coef = a; 
    exponent = b; 
}
```

EDIT 2: My toString method of class Polynomial:

```
public String toString() {

   String temp = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < this.termen.size(); i++) {
        if (i != this.termen.size() - 1)
        temp += this.termen.get(i) + " + ";
      else
        temp += this.termen.get(i);
    }
    return temp; 
}
```

It looks like it keep printing the old list, not the new one. I don't see why exactly.

Comment: Could you post also the class of objects contained by the `Termen? I am interested in the object returned by `termen.get(i)`.

Comment: its the Pair class which contains a double (coef) and an int (exponent)

Comment: @PetrosKoutsolampros yes, you're right.
One more question: `subtract.termen.get(i).coef = subtract.termen.get(i).coef * -1; ` I am not sure I understand what you are doing and I think is missing a paranthesis or something.

Comment: @Setila, I'm multiplying the coefficients times -, because then it's easy to subtract them using a list. :)

Comment: I've added a lot of printlines, and I've noticed that the numbers do change! However, when printing something goes wrong. I can't find the problem, but my toString method must be wrong.

Comment: Did you sort your list right before you called removeDoubles()?

Comment: And also, you say that 1.0x^2 + 13.0x^2 + 2.0 is correct, but shouldnt it be 14x^2 + 1x^1 + 2.0?